# problems with building the android kernel

Tags: android, kernel, linaro

I started building the android core (for nokia 6). Completed make PLE_defconfig(device code name), passed with one warning(arch/arm64/configs/PLE_defconfig:745:warning: symbol value 'm' invalid for WLAN) then made make -j5, and everything came up against errors. What should I do?

Log:
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPYtr.png)

[dir /usr/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBWAF.png)

compiler linaro 4.9.4

Thanks!
(I'm sorry if I'm asking noob questions, I'm just doing it for the first time in my life, and I don't know English)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the error message to be in the **question post** as **text**, not *linked* as *image*. Please, (re-)read [ask] and [edit] your question post correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

AOSP usually ships with `python` packages installed.

Check if you have it with `python2 --version` first.

Or check if you have Python 3 installed with `python3 --version`.

Note: AOSP ships with its own copies of the Python 2 and Python 3 packages, and you can use the version that's included in the source tree. Google is migrating all scripts in the Android source tree to Python 3, and the embedded copy of Python 2 might be deprecated.

You can try to build with Python 3 instead:

```
sudo apt install python3
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python2
```

Or you should download new Android source tree which includes Python 3 script.